# Text semantic preprocessing

Tags: nlp, statistics, data-mining, text-processing, information-retrieval

Let assume that I have a dataset of car accidents. Each accident has a textual description made using a set of cameras and other sensors.

Suppose now I have only the data of a single camera (e.g. the frontal) and I want to remove all the sentences of the description that are not related to it. I think a basic and easy solution could be to use a boolean retrieval system using a set of specific keywords to remove unwanted sentences, but I don't know neither if it is a good idea ner if it could work; could someone suggest me any idea? What kind of statistics might be useful to study this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regex could be one solution.
I created a regex matching the word "front", case insensitive, which searches for front and then get the whole sentences with one or more matches.
The results can be trimmed some from starting white spaces. (Can probably be removed as well with some fine tuning.)

The word you can swap out through some variable taking values from a list, if you need "front", "rear", "side", "right", "left" or other.

[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/ZHU0kr/5) https://regex101.com/r/ZHU0kr/5

Comment: Yes right, this is what I meant with boolean retrieval. Unfortunately this approach fails in many cases because for instance there is not an explicit matching or because you select as a keyword an ambiguous word and remove a sentence which is correct.